# Unable to clear document in bokeh server

Tags: python, bokeh

Here's a sample code I am using to clear a High level chart in a Bokeh server. I would like to add a new High level plot after clearing out the old one by hitting a button, but I am unable to clear the old one. [Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYii4.png)

```
from bokeh.charts import  Bar
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.plotting import  curdoc

from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

button = Button(label="Clear")

def clear():
    curdoc().clear()

p = Bar(df, 'cyl', values='mpg', 
        title="Total MPG by cyl")

button.on_click(clear)
curdoc().add_root(column(button,p) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be issues with trying to completely clear a document in this way. The best current practice is to make the top level of your document some sort of layout (e.g. a `row` or `column`) and then to `update` the children of that layout. In general, as of Bokeh `0.12.3` it is probably true to say that it is more reliable to *update* things, than to *replace* things.

You can see an example of this in the crossfilter example:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/crossfilter/main.py#L72

Where it uses code like this:

```
def update(attr, old, new):
    layout.children[1] = create_figure()
```

Comment: Where is create_figure() from??

Comment: It's not from anywhere, it's a general, notional representation of any function that creates and returns a new `figure` when it is called